# Removing the CListView widget disabled ajax jquery

Tags: yii

I have index view which consits of:

```
<div id="demo" class="demo" style="height:400px;width:600px;"></div>

<?php  $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

Here div id demo is for displaying jquery tree. When I remove widget code. It also don't show the jquery tree data.
I have registered css and jquery in the init() of the modules.
How can I enable the jquery tree data with removing the widget code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do something like

```
<div id="demo" class="demo" style="height:400px;width:600px;"></div>

<?php  $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
), true); ?>
```

Notice the third argument is set to true (default is false), this captures the output so you could do `$out = $this->widget($path, $params, true);` and it would return the HTML into the `$out` variable. In the code above it simply discards the output, no output, no nothing, the init(); is still ran though. So I guess it's what you wanted?

More details here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseController#widget-detail